# Objects not show when change iPhone size storyboard to universal in Xcode 7 iOS Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have iPhone app and storyboard is done.
and every view in story board has iPhone size.
Now i tried to set any any size for views but it has problem.[image]

when change size to iPad (**any any**) , all of objects in views will disappear and then running app , not showing anything in iPad view.
I don't wanna using another storyboard.
Target Device is Universal and i am using Objective C.

Thank you 
Help me. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Resolve the issue with cells not appearing on iPad, needed to add the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods for iPad.

**Original:**

If you get the size classes to regular width and height (iPad size classes), then set the constraints for your objects, I assume they are a width and height of 0, that's why you can't see them.

I think it's better to build constraints for (any, any) and then create specifically for iPhone or iPad if necessary, if you are creating a universal app.

Let if know if you encounter problems, hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: thank you , now not show nib cell in ui collection view . why?

Comment: could you show me a screenshot of your storyboard? Do you use a xib for the content of your collectionview cell? Could you also tell me the frame of your cell and it's contentview?

Comment: Yes i am using xib for cell

Comment: We can continue this in chat if that's better? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow